# Prettier how to customize (JS)

Tags: javascript, prettier

As a rule, "prettier" used everything by default, changing only a few general rules.. spaces, tabs, etc..

But here I have a question, let's say there is an object:

```json
{
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": false
}
```

Can I somehow bring it to this form (pay attention to the spaces), and what do I need for this?

```json
{
  "endOfLine"  : "lf",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi"       : false
}
```

Perhaps `prettier` is not quite suitable for this task, then could you tell me which formatter is better to use? (it is desirable that there is a ready-made plugin for `eslint`)

Comment: I think the spacing shouldn't matter. Your apparent intention to organize your code to make it more readable, perhaps, seems fine, and your suggested method seems fine, as well. Perhaps you could add more information about the problem. What you have asked does not seem to bear any problems.

Comment: Try to add the rule: "alignObjectProperties": true.

The alignObjectProperties option makes sure that all the values in an object are indented to the same level, regardless of their length.

Comment: no, this is not what I'm looking for... I'll try to write a prettier plugin, it looks like what I need
https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html